# How to append javascript into UIWebView in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm trying to change Font in `UIWebView`.
I tried with the following codes to change Font.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *cssPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.css"]; 

    if(!cssPath)
    {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }

    NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var cssChild = document.createElement('link');"
                    "cssChild = 'text/css';"
                    "cssChild = 'stylesheet';"
                    "cssChild = '%@';", cssPath];
    js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cssChild);", js];

    [webViewOfInitial stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

I append css file into header of loaded page from internet.
my css file is following like that.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Zawgyi-One';
    font-style: normal;
    src: local('Zawgyi-One');
}

body {
    font-family: 'Zawgyi-One';
}
```

However when i retrieve html tags when finished page loaded , i can't find my above css tags.
So how do i append that css file into current page of `UIWebView's` header tags?
Or is there any others tutorials for `UIWebView` Font change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are going in the right direction but you haven't mentioned , which delegate method you are trying to make changes in.
you can have your javascript in a .js file as you might make changes to it later and it will be really cumbersome to reflect the changes through code (instead of a js file).Try Using this :-

you have to load the HTML into the view with the correct baseURL parameter to use relative paths or files in UIWebView.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; 
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];     
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

baseURL accepts an NSURL object as the file reference.You can specify a local URL or a web one as your needs leads you to.Append the css file in `webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` as you have done.

NOTE:-Select the .js file and uncheck the bullseye column indicating it as compiled code.(You will just get a warning if you don't).

Here's a[UIWebview Javascript Tutorial](http://www.bitwit.ca/blog/an-native-ios-web-app-tutorialtemplate/) that might get you going.

Comment: If you could, please write a sample project for my question with static HTML Page. I really need. Please.

Comment: htmlstring is your html content ..either it can be a NSString or AN NSString pointing directly to a html file

Comment: Could you help me with sample project?I really need your help.Please.

Comment: HI , i cannot help you with project as i am myself doing one but i am gonna edit a link into my post ..see it ..it has all you need from root..to end